# MongoDB MMS for cluster with keyFile auth

Tags: mongodb

I have a sharded & replicated MongoDB cluster which uses keyFile auth.

I am trying to configure the MongoDB MMS Agent to communicate with all of the cluster members.
I've tried installing MMS on *every* cluster member and informing mms.10gen.com of the IP/port of each cluster member's address. The agent reports that it is unauthorized and I get no data.

It appears that MMS does not support keyFile auth, but is this not the standard production cluster setup?

How can I set up MMS for this kind of cluster?

Comment: This question isn't a good fit for StackOverflow.

Comment: Thanks, @WiredPrairie, I've posted it to the MongoDB mailing list https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/mongodb-user/mms|sort:date/mongodb-user/2X_Jxdeso98/m0XqYxuMLokJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted this on the 10gen-mms mailing list and found the answer.

keyFile authentication is meant only for intra-cluster communication and communication between MongoS instances and the cluster.

Specifying keyFile auth means that you can access the cluster without a username/password via MongoS (with keyFile) if no users exist.

If a user is created, then user auth is additionally required.

You can create a user locally on each of the MongoD instances and use that to connect directly to them without a keyFile.

So the solution was to create users for MMS and my front-end service and to use user authentication.